# Recommended way to encode/decode URLs

Tags: escaping, go

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encode / decode URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820280/encode-decode-urls)

What's the recommended way to encode/decode URLs in Go? I am looking to the equivalent of [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) in JavaScript.

Comment: here we are: https://github.com/alessiosavi/GoCloudant/blob/a8ad3a7990f04ea728bb327d6faea6af3e5455ca/cloudant.go#L116

Answer (score 33):

You're looking for the "net/url" package.

http://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#QueryEscape

Comment: Of course, thanks. I don't know how I overlooked it.

Comment: That does a query-style escape, which isn't the equivalent of `encodeURIComponent()`.

Comment: For example, it replaces spaces with `+` instead of `%20`.

Comment: I see that, so what would be the equivalent?

Comment: I created a string helper function that resembles `encodeURIComponent()` https://github.com/mrap/stringutil/blob/master/urlencode.go

Comment: `Escape` **x** `encodeURIComponent` are different unicode, best is `encodeURIComponent`