# How to decode golang url.QueryEscape data in javascript?

Tags: javascript, go

I have a string in JS side which is `url.QueryEscape`d.

Spaces were replaced with + sign by `url.QueryEscape`. They don't get converted back to space in `decodeURIComponent`. Should I manually do a string replace all + with space? What is the right way to decode it?

Comment: Maybe this link can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820280/encode-decode-urls

Answer (score 2):

One simple method is to replace all the `+` characters with spaces prior to decoding.  For example:

```
decodeURIComponent("%2f+%2b".replace(/\+/g, " "))
```

will correctly decode the string to `"/ +"`.  Note that it is necessary to perform the replacement prior to decoding, since there could be encoded `+` characters in the string.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I did, but was wondering if I will miss some other encoded characters like space

Comment: The Go `QueryEscape` function just encodes spaces as plus, and uses percent encoding for other characters not valid in a URL query component.  So `replace` and `decodeURIComponent` on the JS side should handle everything.

Comment: Just a note, the correct way to do a replace all would be to enclose the search string in a RegExp global modifier like so

`decodeURIComponent("%2f+%2b".replace(/\+/g, " "))`

Answer (score 1):

If you control Go side, use `url.PathEscape` and then you can simply use `decodeURIComponent` without anything extra.