# URL Escaping producing "%A(MISSING)" instead of "%3A"

Tags: url, go, revel

I am using the revel framework with the go language. Recently, when I run the following code:

```
import (
    ...
    "net/url"
    ...
)

revel.INFO.Println(url.QueryEscape("http://hello.com"))
```

I get

```
INFO  2014/07/09 14:58:34 user.go:39: http%A(MISSING)%F(MISSING)%F(MISSING)hello.com
```

When I expect to get something more like

```
INFO  2014/07/09 14:58:34 user.go:39: http%3A%2F%2Fhello.com
```

Why has `%3A` been replaced by `%A(MISSING)` in the output and how can I fix it?

The only go code where I see something that might produce the string "(MISSING)' is in the `fmt` package, but from looking at the `net/url` source code package, I don't see how that could be happening. Am I perhaps somehow accessing an old (and broken?) version of the go libraries? Is something else possibly wrong with my setup?

Related: [Encode / decode URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820280/encode-decode-urls)

Relevant Go Source code: http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/url/url.go?s=14330:14361#L553

Comment: It seems revel is broken and is using Printf...

Comment: This did not even occur to me. Wow. I'm sitting here reinstalling everything and feeling pretty stupid. :-P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`revel.INFO.Println` is like `fmt.Printf`, it expects a format string and arguments. To log a string that contains `%` characters you either need to escape it, or better pass it as an argument:

```
revel.INFO.Println("The escaped URL is: %s", url.QueryEscape("http://hello.com"))
```

(You could just use `"%s"` as the format string, but why not take the chance to provide context.)

Comment: Yeah--it sounds more like `revel.INFO.Println` is like `Printf`.

Comment: Right, sorry. I'll fix the answer. Thanks!