# How to add a string to an URL in golang?

Tags: rest, go

I am new to golang and trying this for the first time. I have to call yahoo finance api(YQL) to get the stock price of the symbol in json format.
Here is the api:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20LastTradePriceOnly%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22AAPL%22,%22FB%22,%22GOOG%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys
```

For now i have hard coded the symbol(AAPL,FB, GOOG) in the above select query but these symbols will be coming from the user, it should be dynamic. How should i add the input(symbol) to the above query in golang?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Well, have you tried to concatenate the strings?

Comment: No i haven't..i am not sure how should i go ahead with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the symbols (provided by the users) as a string array parameter (like: "`symbols`", being `string["\"AAPL\"", "\"FB\"", "\"GOOG\""]`), you can use [`strings/#Join`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Join) to produce the right string:

```
s := strings.Joins(symbols, ",")
```

Then (as detailed in "[Encode / decode URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13820280/6309)"), use [`net/url/#QueryEscape`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#QueryEscape) to get the final url string for symbols:

```
url := "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20LastTradePriceOnly%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20(" + 
url.QueryEscape(s) + 
")&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys"
```

Comment: Alternatively you could put all the query parts into a [`url.Values`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values) and then use [`Values.Encode`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values.Encode) to get the entire URL part after the `?`.