# Is there a standard way to encode a URI component containing both forward-slashes and whitespace in Go?

Tags: go, escaping

I'm interacting with an API which takes URI components that may contain both forward-slashes and spaces. I need to percent-encode this URI component so that both the forward-slashes and spaces are properly encoded. Example Go code can be found **[here](https://play.golang.org/p/loaa8vvCli)**.

I turned to `net/url` to tackle this, but turns out it doesn't do what I want, apparently.

- `url.QueryEscape()` is intended for query strings, and as such it turns whitespace into `+` rather than `%20`.
- `url.Parse()` and `url.ParseRequestUri()` will turn whitespace into `%20`, but it will ignore `/`, as it should.

Since I'm very likely to muck this up (escaping is [non-trivial](https://golang.org/src/net/url/url.go?s=6331:6364#L97)), I'd prefer I relied upon some standard library out there to do this for me. Does such a standard method exist in a well-tested Go library?

Side note: The behaviour I'm seeking is identical to JS's `encodeURIcomponent`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encode / decode URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820280/encode-decode-urls)

Comment: I did review that question before posting. It is not a duplicate, as the question and solution provided does not account for or work with escaping of forward slashes in the URI components.

Comment: What do you want exactly? The _exact_ equivalent of JavaScript's `encodeURIComponent()`?

Comment: Something which will appropriately encode a URI component which includes forward slashes and spaces. I was hoping there was a standard lib out there to do so, but apparently there isn't - I created this as an issue on Golang's GH and it was tagged with Go1.8.

Comment: For those who want to follow the progress of the github issue, here's the link: [net/url: No adequate method exists for encoding a URI component #16207](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16207)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently a version of your issue made it in [go1.8](https://go-review.googlesource.com/#/c/31322/) as `url.PathEscape`.

In go1.8 the code you're looking for would be as simple as:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

const expected = "/object/test%2Fbar%20baz"

func main() {
    uri := "/object/"
    name := "test/bar baz"

    fmt.Printf("%-25s %s\n", "Expected:", expected)
    fmt.Printf("%-25s %s\n", "Actual  :", uri+url.PathEscape(name))
}
```

Good question.